# Icinga2 crash logs not generated

Tags: crash, logging, icinga2

I am trying to crash Icinga2 and generate some crash reports under /var/log/icinga2/crash/ but there is no crash report generated.
I tried to kill icinga2 service with different kill signal and still no luck.
Can someone please give me some suggestion on this, am I missing something ?
Thank you.